# Parse and extract parts of UK Post code

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to seperate Uk post code into area, district, sector. For e.g

if I have a post code like  B75 5TW

I want the output as

1. B75 5TW
2. B75 5
3. B75
4. B7

I tried this regex but doesn't work as expected.

```
^([A-Z]{1,2})([0-9][0-9A-Z]?)\s*([0-9])([A-Z]{2})$

var regex = new Regex(@"^([A-Z]{1,2})([0-9][0-9A-Z]?)\s*([0-9])([A-Z]{2})$");
var matches = regex.Match(postcode);

Output should be like below
    matches.groups[0] - B75 5TW
    matches.groups[1] - B75 5
    ...etc
```

Any help much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Try `^(((([A-Z]{1,2})[0-9][0-9A-Z]?)\s*[0-9])[A-Z]{2})$`

Comment: wow thanks @juharr It seems to work. But one small problem first two items have the same value.

     matches.groups[0] - B75 5TW
     matches.groups[1] - B75 5TW

Comment: Yeah, group 0 is always the whole thing, so you could ignore it or remove the outer most parenthesis.

Comment: Ok, understood whats the purpose of () in regex. thanks. 

If you can post it as answer, I would accept it as answer.

Comment: The parenthesis are used to create the various groups of the overall match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work you want to nest your groups like so

```
^((([A-Z]{1,2})[0-9][0-9A-Z]?)\s*[0-9])[A-Z]{2}$
```